# Rails XML builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I have controller action in my rails application to output XML which in turn is used to generate a FusionChart. I am using a builder template for generating XML. Below is the code that is in builder template.

```
xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new  
xml.chart(:palette=>'2', ....) do  
 for item in @domain_data  
  xml.set(:label=>item[:domain],:value=>item[:emp_count])  
 end  
end
```

This code throws error in all the browsers. When I move the code to controller and use the below snippet,

```
xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new  
    xml.chart(:palette=>'2', :ca...) do  
     for item in @domain_data  
   xml.set(:label=>item[:domain],:value=>item[:emp_count])  
 end  
end  
send_data xml, :type=>"text/xml"
```

it works fine in Google Chrome/firefox etc but returns an empty file in Internet Explorer. Can somebody tell me what might be wrong here?  Thanks in advance // Abhi

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten about an XML declaration:

```
xml.instruct!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately that did not help. //Abhi